# How do I overcome the TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to calculate the Latitude and Longitude for a number (series) of flights in which I tried to use this code

```py
import pandas as pd
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
# convert decimal degrees to radians 
lon1 = df1['from_lon'].map(radians)
lat1 = df1['from_lat'].map(radians)
lon2 = df1['dest_lon'].map(radians)
lat2 = df1['dest_lat'].map(radians)
# haversine formula 
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
results = 3959.0 * c
```

but I keep getting this error

```py
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I have seen many people asking about this error on stackoverflow and tried the answers provided to them. What I have tried is to use the equation in this way

```py
a = dlat.divide(2).apply(sin).pow(2) + cos(lat1) * lat2.apply(cos).multiply(dlon.divide(2).apply(sin).pow(2))
```

I also tried to use `lambda` as well as tried to convert each variable to float using `.astype(float)` but unfortunately nothing worked with me.

The data type for lon1, lat1, lon2 and lat2 is `float64`.a sample of the data:

```py
lon1
-1.826892
-1.287685
-1.534229
-1.534229
-1.826892
1.775173
-0.062252
```

Comment: show some of your data and dtypes.

Comment: @mark I have added what you asked for in the post. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you try this code and see the output if this is what you want. (no error for me but not sure if the output is correct or not)

`a = (dlat/2).apply(lambda x : sin(x)) ** 2  + lat1.apply(lambda x : cos(x)) * lat2.apply(lambda x:cos(x))* (dlon/2).apply(lambda x : sin(x)) ** 2`


`c = 2 * a.apply(lambda x : asin(sqrt(x)))`


`results = 3959.0 * c`

Comment: @Vishal yes that did the job perfectly thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code which works without error. Basically you need to use Series.apply(lambda x: ) function.

```
a = (dlat/2).apply(lambda x : sin(x)) ** 2 + lat1.apply(lambda x : cos(x)) * lat2.apply(lambda x:cos(x))* (dlon/2).apply(lambda x : sin(x)) ** 2 
c = 2 * a.apply(lambda x : asin(sqrt(x))) 
results = 3959.0 * c
```